# Java Swing GUI Console Component

Tags: java, swing, io

I'm currently creating my first java swing application and as part of the GUI I have a small console in the form of a JTextField component. I would like to be able to print to this console from anywhere in the application using a command like ***console.print(String)***. I believe that I should be using print stream but I can't figure out how to make this work properly from anywhere (i.e. in another class which doesn't reference the console) .
I would also like to maintain the ability to print out to the eclipse console. Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: So for example the application handles downloads of items from some separate class completely separate to this GUI element. I'd like to send a message to the console from that download element whilst the downloads are happening to give status updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for the purpose of accepting and distributing console strings; give it a static method to print to your console.  Give that class a (static) reference to your console component.

something like:

```
public MyConsole
{
  private static TextField field;
  public static void setField(TextField givenField)
  {
    field = givenField;
  }

  public static void print(String msg)
  {
    field.append(msg);
  }
}
```

The other parts of your application can import MyConsole and call `MyConsole.print(msg);`

Comment: This solutions works perfectly in most situations I have just tested, but for some reason in a switch I have where a *System.out.println* was working this won't print. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Sorry I should mention that is in a swing worker process method

Comment: System.out.println normally sends text to your program console, it won't appear anywhere in the GUI.  If you use a command-line window to start your Swing program (something like "java -jar MyProgram.jar", then the System.out.println messages will appear in that window.